# ngApp without using any specific module name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the piece of code below:

part of html file:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">{{name}}</div>
</body>
```

part of js file:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = "John";
}
```

I always put my controllers in some module, whose name I define in ng-app. 
How it works when I don't define any module ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Angular, has this "auto-discover" feature, that allows it to look up controllers by their name if they are defined on the global scope.

This feature is mainly intended for quick demos/prototypes/proof-of-concept snippets and not real-world applications.

---

From Angular's **[Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)**:

> **NOTE:** Although Angular allows you to create Controller functions in the global scope, this is not recommended. In a real application you should use the `.controller` method of your Angular Module for your application [...]

---

Regarding the empty `ngApp`, if there is no name specified, it only means that there is no module to assign controllers, directives, services to, but other than that everything works fine.

Comment: I find it peculiar how Angular permits this demonstration usage of controllers without modules and not other constructs like directives and filters. AFAIK, the latter needs to be under a module to be used.

Comment: I believe that the main reasoning for allowing global controllers is to allow for easily putting together short demos (e.g. to show-case 2-way data-binding etc), while avoiding the complexity of declaring modules. Directives and filters are inherently much more complex (both in concept and in implementation), so the extra complexity of declaring a module is negligible (i.e. compared to the complexity of explaining  directive).

Comment: OK so say I start with `ng-app` only but then add a name? I loose the functionality of the demo. How do I keep the functionality of the demo? In this case I'm using `ng-model="qty"` and `ng-model="cost"` to do arithmetic, outputting to `Total: {{qty * cost | currency}}`.

Comment: @FrankDraws: Not sure what you are talking about (without seeing any code), but note that recently-ish, the global controllers feature has been deprecated and is disabled by default (it can be enabled, but it's not recommended). You should use a proper Angular Module (e.g. `<html ng-app="myApp">...` and `angular.module('myApp', [])...`).