# Difference between defining a variable using ng-model, not by a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't understand the behavior of a variable in the following two different code snippet.

```
<body ng-app="">
<input ng-model="name">
{{name}}
</body>
```

The above code doesn't uses any controller for the variable 'name'

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="NameController">
<input ng-model="name">
{{name}}

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('NameController', function($scope) {
$scope.name="";
});
</body>
```

In this code snippet, I have used a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $scope in an AngularJS is a built-in object, which contains application data and methods. You can create properties to a $scope object inside a controller function and assign a value or function to it.

in the second case you defined variable in scope of function it will not available out side and you have to use inside the controller you dont need to get the variable value from dom if you want to pass the value of name you can use $scope.name

1st one is just assign ngModel in html if you want to use the value you have to get the value from angular.element() function other you can just print it in html

Answer (score 0):

I did some quick research on SO and came to the conclusion that in the first case everything is simply being defined in the global scope of the application and the application has no name so you are basically unable to assign any controllers, directives etc. to your application but it's working.

The second way is the right way to do it: your application (or module) has a name, it is assigned to a variable and therefore you can assign factories, controllers, directives etc. to the application.

Source: [ngApp without using any specific module name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054536/ngapp-without-using-any-specific-module-name)

Comment: In your second method, the variable is still in global scope of the application, na?

Comment: What variable are you referring to? If you are speaking of the `ng-model="name"` then the `name` variable is on the scope of the `NameController` and not on the global scope.
Also, variable `app` is in this case a global variable.