# Not able to read data from Controller in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

can anyone point the mistake as to why i am unable to read the data from the controller ?

Link to plunker

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4jnawDJgdMM61GYfpxor?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js.1.3@*" data-semver="1.5.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1> {{ message }} </h1>
  </body>

</html>

// Code goes here

// Code goes here

var MainController = function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "Hello";
};
```

Comment: Whats the message you are getting in `console log` of browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code may be correct, but it is prior to the versions `1.3.0`

**Versions Before `1.3.0`:**

> Prior to 1.3.0, angular was able to automatically discover controllers
>   that were defined globally.

**Check Below I have created without module**

```
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="MainController">
       {{message}}
   </div>
</div>
```

**The code can be:**

```js
var MainController = function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "Hello";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.32/angular.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}} </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

[**Plunker version prior to 1.3.0**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CYI8cPzVeImpGWuPoB96?p=catalogue)

---

**Versions After 1.3.0:**

You can use **`$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()`** to enable that behaviour.

> `allowGlobals` allows `$controller` to find controller constructors on
>   window

```js
angular.module("ng").config(function($controllerProvider){
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
});

var MainController = function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "Hello";
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function MyController() {}
    </script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}} </h1>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

[**Plunker with versions after 1.3.0**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kclWqaYtFL876SOqCiiJ?p=preview)

> Note: I personally recommend to use the latest versions with modules
>   and `ng-app="app"` format.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('MainController',function($scope){ .. your code ...})
```

Comment: @Rahul Raj, I mentioned why it is not working and also gave the solution to how to make it work using your syntax after version `1.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

Where is the `ng-app` name ?  Provide module name.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('SomeCtrl',function($scope){ .. your code ...})
```

Provide it in `.html` file

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Fixed your [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/W2N6yPR5fwN6ZZ3EMzou?p=preview)

> You are referring to older version of AngularJS for learning and using 1.5 in plunkr. Check the below link

For your app, refer

1. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054536/ngapp-without-using-any-specific-module-name)
2. [and this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value)

Comment: i don't think thats necessary .Anyway i gave ng-app="Test".But it still doesnt work

Comment: @RahulRaj: Not necessary? Share your console log

Comment: is it due to old version ?
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Test due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Test' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: why module i am learnimng from pluralsight video and i copied the same code.There was no mention of concept module

Comment: @RahulRaj : Check the plunkr in my answer

Comment: @shashank.It works but why mine wasn't working.Need an explanation

Comment: @RahulRaj , Check the plunkr in my answer. its fixed. also you have app.js which I fixed with script.js

Comment: Shashank i got the reason why my code wasn't working.Thanks.My code works well for version 1.3

Comment: @RahulRaj : Cool, not sure why your question was downvoted , is seemed ok to me. Cheers. . If u got you want, mark it as an answer.

Comment: where is it down voted?Can't see.And how can i marm my question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">

      <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js.1.3@*" data-semver="1.5.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1> {{ message }} </h1>
  </body>

</html>

// Code goes here
```

script.js

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('MainController',function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Hello";
})
```